# Changing the Peer Pressure badge description

Tags: feature-request, badges

The [Peer Pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) states it is given when you:

> Delete own post with score of -3 or lower.

I have 3 posts deleted on Meta with a rank of less than -3 (links for the 10K users: [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389411/self-accepted-answer-48-hour-limitation-can-we-improve-it-by-notify-the-op), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389131/marking-post-with-status-complete-tag-as-answered) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387466/shall-we-have-badges-for-editing-posts-which-significantly-improve-them)) - But I only got the badge once.

It make sense to give it only once (and not multiple times). But if so, should it be defined as:

> First deletion of own post with score of -3 or lower.

(As per the [citizen-patrol badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) which has the text:

> **First** flagged post.

Comment: These badges were meant to help new users discover site features and encourage good behavior.  Important, don't leave trash lying around.  Doubtful that they'll want to emphasize that they should only cleanup once.

Comment: @HansPassant if the idea behind the badge is to encourage user delete bad post then we can keep this one for first deletion and add other (silver and gold) for 5 and 20 deletion (corresponded)  - we can call it "self-cleaner" (the threshold and the name are negotiate-able

Comment: @dWinder I don't think we want to encourage people to get themselves post banned either.

Comment: @RobertLongson - agreed - that why I said "if the idea behaind it..." - I think we just need to change the description to **"First...**" as the actual status currently

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's working exactly as intended. Plenty of badges don't mention you can only get them once.

Comment: Because many badge DO mention to be first time if they are once-only I think we should use the same phrase in all badge descriptions - so take it as my post address more badge and it more general

Comment: This is already the default for most badges - the rest say *"This badge can be awarded multiple times."* on the badge page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The language isn't ambiguous, since there's existing language to describe badges which *can* be awarded multiple times.

> Answer score of 100 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Any badge lacking the second fragment can only ever be awarded once.

Comment: Something that would make this more explicit is a mention at the top of the list pointing out that badges can only be received once unless otherwise noted. As it stands, the descriptions depend on users assuming that to be the case or divining it from seeing that note on some of them.

Comment: Do notice this second fragment is only shown in the inner page and not on the all-badge-main-page